# Python Kivy filechooser adding multiple files to a list

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

I'm fairly new to Python and also Kivy and it's been giving me a hard time with this issue. The filechooser is working, also can choose multiple files but it only adds the last chosen file to the list and not the rest. What am I doing wrong?

Py File

```
class UploadWindow(Screen):
    paths = StringProperty()
    text_input = StringProperty()

    def show_load_list(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load_list, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load the sound files", content=content, size_hint=(.5, .5))
        self._popup.open()

    def load_list(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0]), encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as stream:
            filename_actual = os.path.basename(filename.pop())
            global importedfiles
            importedfiles.append((filename_actual, path))
            print(importedfiles)

        self.dismiss_popup()

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Kv file

```
<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser
            path: './'
            filters: ['*.wav']
            multiselect: True
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()
            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release:
                    root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: In your `load_list` method, add the line `print(filename)` at the start. I suspect that `filename` is actually a list of filenames, and you are only loading the one at index `0`.